# Query custom post type with jQuery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-post-type, wordpress

Im working on a site [see here](http://greyediting201.staging.wpengine.com/projects/) and I created a custom post type named "projects".
When the page initially loads, Everything works fine, all the post data is loaded. But when I use `$.load()` to load the same code from an external file  nothing gets displayed. It only appears to be a problem with custom post types, if I subsitute "projects" with "post" (the default type) the "Hello World" post will be re-queried,but not the "projects".

How can I query a custom post type twice? Here's my code:

```html
<?php 
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'projects',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'nonfiction'
   )
  );


 $query = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $query->have_posts() ):
  while ( $query->have_posts() ):
  $query->the_post(); 
  $meta_data = array( 
   'author' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Author', true),
   'publisher' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Publisher', true),
   'year' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Year', true),
   'role'  => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Role', true),
   'location' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Location', true)
   );

?>

 <li>
  <?php 
   echo $meta_data['author']; 
   echo ". ";
   the_title(); 
   echo " (" . $meta_data['location'] . ": " . $meta_data['publisher'] . ", " . $meta_data['year'] . "). " . $meta_data['role'];
   
  ?>
 </li>

<?php 
  endwhile;
 endif;
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tab').click(function(){
   $('.publications').load('http://greyediting201.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/pp_boot/_nonfiction.php', null, console.log('finished'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in .load() function do not use server url but relative path such as ./path of js folder/js file.js. hope it will work for you

[Just check the link here for jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed me code to a relative path and still nothing. the problem isn't loading the file, its getting the posts to display a second time

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tab').click(function(){
   $('.publications').load('../wp-content/themes/pp_boot/_nonfiction.php', null, console.log('finished'));
  });
 });

</script>

Comment: so the problem is that you are able to load posts once but not second time right? if yes than we have a solution for this. And where from this Hello world text is coming?

Comment: Yes thats exactly the problem. The hello world is just the same code calling posts of type "post" for testing purposes to ensure my code isn't broken

Comment: give me original link or path who is providing same result that you are getting on page load. i will provide you answer for sure. Your code is working fine. add some good content in this publication post and let me know than i will check this

Comment: http://greyediting201.staging.wpengine.co/wp-content/themes/pp_boot/_nonfiction.php   this?

Comment: this url should work on click. its not working and saying invalid url. give me working url dude and see magic :)

Comment: http://greyediting201.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/pp_boot/_nonfiction.php

Comment: so this url is working and on click of this url result comes Hello world and same is coming in custom post also so what do you want now?

Comment: the text that follows should also be displayed but its not...Bollinger, Michelle, and Dao X.. Tran, eds., 101 Changemakers: Rebels and Radicals Who Changed History (Chicago: Haymarket Books, 2014). Copy editor
Bellamy Foster, John. “Introduction,” in Paul Burkett, Marx and Nature: A Red and Green Perspective (Chicago: Haymarket Books, 2014). Copy editor
Bale, Jeff, and Sarah Knopp. Education and Capitalism (Chicago: Haymarket Books, 2012). Proofreader
Ammori, Marvin. On Internet Freedom (Washington, D.C.: Elkat Books, 2013). Manuscript editor

Comment: @dburgess923 its not javascript or jQuery error its your wordpress problem as whenever we open the url you provided it gives only Hello world not complete output that you want. something is wrong at server side code just check it

Comment: Thanks! I figured it wasn't an issue with javascript, jus thought it might be the combination of the two. I think I may just change the functionality around and use the default post type instead. again thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

i think .load work in relative urls only otherwise any cross-domain issuses

Comment: Thanks for replying, I changed the code to a relative path and still no luck. the file loads just fine, but the are no posts in the query.

Comment: ohh you are saying it's start to request again when user clicks the tab

Comment: Exactly! But the custom posts aren't called. Only the default posts are.